# Deep evaluation of variables

Tags: python

I have a need to use local().update to load some variables from configuration.

The problem is that there are dependencies between them, and i need to evaluate their real values.

For example if run this code:

```
vars={'x':'z','y':'4','z':'y'}
locals().update(vars)
print (eval(x))
```

the final result should be x=4, but the assigned value initially is x='y'

Comment: Can't you just print((vars[eval(x)]))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def deep(key):
    keyChecked = []
    while vars[key] in vars.keys() and key not in keyChecked:
        keyChecked.append(key)
        key = vars[key]
    else:
        return vars[key]
vars={'x':'z','y':'4','z':'y'}
print(deep('x'))
```

I think you will get expected answer.

Comment: Will work, as long as there is no confict between some string value being the same as some variable name!

Comment: I am just passing key to dictionary instead of variable name

Comment: Sure, i just want to warn, that if, e.g. variable `z` is meant to hold a string `'y'`, this solution could fail. Nothing more.

Comment: @SimonFink I have updated it now if there is any loop in keys and value it will ended up to last key